# json.net format for charts.js in asp mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

After a lot of work I have obtained a string in Json that should be processed in HTML. The correct format should be:

```
 { 
     labels: ['America','Europa', 'Global','Oceania'],
     datasets: [{
         data: [0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.40],
         backgroundColor: ['#a3aaf7','#89a8ff', '#01469b', '#0d1156'],
         hoverBackgroundColor: ['#beed9e', '#84ffbd', '#0afb00', '#058217']
      }]  }
```

while the one obtained by my script is:

```
"{\"labels\":[\"Equity\"],
\"datasets\":{
\"data\":[1.00000],
\"backgroundColor\":[\"#a3aaf7\"],
\"hoverBackgroundColor\":[\"#beed9e\"]}}"
```

So I should, first of all, delete the \ before the " character and, secondarely, put a [ after the second element (datasets) that should be closed at the end.

Unfortunately I'm using Json.net as library, so I do not have the full control of the string.
I create, in the model side, the class with the 2 propeties labels and datasets, and for the last one, another class with the classes data, backgroundcolor and hoverbackgroundcolor. I put all togheter usinf the function json.serailizedobject and, on the view side, my code is this one:

```
<script>
    var _tipologia=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tipologie_json));
    var tipologia=JSON.parse(_tipologia.textContent);
    window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("Tipologia").getContext("2d");
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'pie', data: tipologia });
}
</script>
```

Any idea on how to make it work? thankx

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE

I have partially solved. With this code:

```
<script type="application/json" id="tipologia_js">@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tipologie_json).Replace("*", "'"));</script>
<script>
    var tipologia = JSON.parse(document.getelementbyid(tipologia_js).textcontent);
    console.log(tipologia);
    window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("Tipologia").getContext("2d");
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'pie', data: tipologia });
}
```

I obtain this html:

```
</form>        
<script type="application/json" id="tipologia_js">"{'labels':['Equity'],'datasets':[{'data':[1.00000],'backgroundColor':['#a3aaf7'],'hoverBackgroundColor':['#beed9e']}]}";</script>
<script>
    var tipologia = JSON.parse(document.getelementbyid(tipologia_js).textcontent);
    window.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("Tipologia").getContext("2d");
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'pie', data: tipologia });
}
</script>
```

and it doesn't work only for a problem of parsing. Infact the code

```
<script>


    var AG={'labels':['Equity'],'datasets':[{'data':[1.00000],'backgroundColor':['#a3aaf7'],'hoverBackgroundColor':['#beed9e']}]};
    window.onload = function () {
    var ctxa = document.getElementById("Areageografica").getContext("2d");
    var myPieChart1 = new Chart(ctxa, { type: 'pie', data: AG });
}
    </script>
```

that is really close, works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(tipologia)`

Comment: Hackerman, thansk for your interest. How can I obtain that?

Comment: Put that line of code below this line `var tipologia=JSON.parse(_tipologia.textContent);`....press F12, check the console tab and post the result.

Comment: Hackerman I can't find this data... f12 doesn't work. In any case I have partially solved. with this code:

Comment: Can't you just parse the string back into an object in Javascript? `JSON.parse`

Comment: I tryed also with JSON.parse that is in any case embedded in the code above. UNfortunatelly it doesn't change the bad result...

Comment: any advise? I do not have any idea on how to sort  i out...